# Drawing a filled 180deg arc in Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael

I've just started playing with SVG and Raphael.js and am trying to draw a filled arc but not sure how to start.  I'm trying to draw a basic padlock and have the body and two parts of the bolt to fit the arc on top.  It's basically a filled 180deg arc, 10 pixels wide.  I'm guessing I need to use the .path() but not sure of the syntax or whether I want to be using "curveTo" or "arc" - struggling to find any good SVG or Raphael tutorial sites to be honest.

```
var padlockBody = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5);
padlockBody.attr("fill", "#000000");

var leftBoltPart = paper.rect(120, 70, 10, 30);
leftBoltPart.attr("fill", "#000000");

var rightBoltPart = paper.rect(170, 70, 10, 30);
rightBoltPart.attr("fill", "#000000");

// TODO: filled arc to fit on top of left/right bolt parts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arcs are notoriously challenging to write by hand (in pure SVG or in Raphael, it's the same).

I usually extend Raphael with these methods (credits belong to [the55](https://gist.github.com/812657))

```
// http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands
Raphael.fn.arc = function(startX, startY, endX, endY, radius1, radius2, angle) {
  var arcSVG = [radius1, radius2, angle, 0, 1, endX, endY].join(' ');
  return this.path('M'+startX+' '+startY + " a " + arcSVG);
};

Raphael.fn.circularArc = function(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
  var startX = centerX+radius*Math.cos(startAngle*Math.PI/180); 
  var startY = centerY+radius*Math.sin(startAngle*Math.PI/180);
  var endX = centerX+radius*Math.cos(endAngle*Math.PI/180); 
  var endY = centerY+radius*Math.sin(endAngle*Math.PI/180);
  return this.arc(startX, startY, endX-startX, endY-startY, radius, radius, 0);
};
```

You can find a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cahT9/

Comment: Thanks, would have been +2 if I could for adding the jsFiddle example.  Realised that I should have done that last night after posting, but thanks for going to that extra trouble.